# Sympify a string (SymPy)

Tags: python, sympy

I've just started learning Python, and I'm exploring the SymPy library.

A `string` can be converted into a SymPy expression, upon which we can `lambdify` it:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.Symbol('x')
f_symp = sp.sympify('sin(x)')
f_lamb = sp.lambdify(x,f)
```

So far so good - but I've also seen `lambdify` being used on a `string`:

```
f_lamb2 = sp.lambdify(x,'sin(x)')
```

And it works (to my surprise). In the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html#lambdify) for `lambdify` I didn't see it mentioned that the input can be a string.

So my question is: is this appropriate usage of `lambdify`, or could this result in complications that wouldn't occur if `sympify` was used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both approaches are valid, it is simply a question of clarity.

**lambdify** is designed to work with arguments that are sympy expressions or strings. Thus if you need to create a function directly without reusing the expression you can directly write it as a string. This can come in handy for one-time expressions.

However if you need to use that same expression later in the code I would advise you to sympify it to avoid overloaded code.

Hope this answered your question!